# kernel panic after Linux updates

Tags: kernel, boot, panic

[image]

Please, can someone give me step-by-step instructions how to get back into my Linux Cinnamon operating system.

I updated the definitions. After a reboot this issue appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every distro I've seen keeps at least one prior kernel version available in grub if not more.  My multiple 18.x updated across versions Mint system has 11 at the moment....

So, in the grub menu, select an older kernel, boot that, remove bad kernel, update grub.  If you don't see the grub menu press the shift key on your keyboard at the end of the BIOS stage of your computer.

FWIW it looks like the initrd didn't get updated properly either for file system drivers, hard drive controller, etc. OR the reference to the root file system is wrong.

**EDIT**  - to remove the bad kernel, etc.

Get a list of installed kernels on your system -

```
user@darkstar ~ $ dpkg -l | grep "Linux kernel"
ii  cpufrequtils                                 008-1                                        amd64        utilities to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
ii  kmod                                         22-1ubuntu5                                  amd64        tools for managing Linux kernel modules
ii  libaio1:amd64                                0.3.110-2                                    amd64        Linux kernel AIO access library - shared library
ii  libaio1:i386                                 0.3.110-2                                    i386         Linux kernel AIO access library - shared library
ii  libcpufreq0                                  008-1                                        amd64        shared library to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
ii  linux-firmware                               1.157.17                                     all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-21                       4.4.0-21.37                                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic               4.4.0-21.37                                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-53                       4.4.0-53.74                                  all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic               4.4.0-53.74                                  amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic                 4.4.0-21.37                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic                 4.4.0-53.74                                  amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic           4.4.0-21.37                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic           4.4.0-53.74                                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-kernel-generic                         4.4.0-53                                     all          The Linux kernel.
ii  ndiswrapper                                  1.60-3~ubuntu16.04.2                         amd64        Userspace utilities for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel module
ii  ndiswrapper-dkms                             1.60-3~ubuntu16.04.2                         all          Source for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel module (DKMS)

user@darkstar ~ $
```

First, if `linux-image-generic` is installed remove it.  It is a meta package that keeps your kernel up with latest releases.  Then remove the offending version.

```
user@darkstar ~ $ sudo apt-get remove kernel-image-generic
... apt doing stuff ...
user@darkstar ~ $ sudo apt-get remove kernel-image-x.y.z-a-generic
```

When a new release is made, you can install it specifically and test it - if it works, you can reinstall the kernel-image-generic to keep up to date on releases

Comment: Thanks very much I chose in the advanced menu a different version. So now that I am in how to I delete the kernel that doesn’t work

Comment: @tomcolgan - editing answer